# JavaScript set content editable value to variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, contenteditable

I have a content editable `<p>` tag in html and a button. I'm wondering how I can make it so that when the button is pressed, the variable called content will be set to the value inside of the content editable p tag . For example, if you type in the `<p>` tag "Hello world" and press the button, the variable content will have a value of "Hello world"

Code:

```
<p contenteditable="true">
hi
</p>

<button onclick="update()">
Update
</button>

<script>
function update() {
var content = "content of content editable"
console.log (content)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Straightforwardly: name the p element with an ID, use Javascript to find the DOM object that is p by name, swap out the val. You could do it as is, by iterating the DOM tree to find the p element but I suspect there will be more elements on your page and identifiers make identifying things easy.

Comment: innerHTML or innerText

Answer (score 2):

You'd start by wanting to avoid any issues by using inline-script. So first things first get rid of the onclick and give each element you'll be using for this operation a specific ID.

Next we'll querySelect the element/button and apply an event listener for our button to know when it's clicked to react appropriately.

Below is an example. It's a bit of a duplication but should be okay.

```js
function update() {
  return "content of content editable";
}
// Select the submit button
document.querySelector("#editable_submit").addEventListener("pointerup", (event) => {
  // Button Clicked
  document.querySelector("#editable_box").innerText = update(); // Update Editable Box
}, {
  passive: true
});
```

```html
<p id="editable_box" contenteditable="true">
  hi
</p>

<button id="editable_submit">
Update
</button>
```

Comment: *and give each element you'll be using for this operation a specific ID* <-- This is not a scalable solution. Relying on `id`s creates brittle code that causes problems down the line.  It's far better to avoid `id`s whenever possible and use other methods to locate the appropriate elements (i.e. by class, by location, by attribute, etc.).

Comment: Verbose won't throw for thousands of IDs, you're fine.

Comment: No, your not. Try dynamically adding/deleting records when the elements have `id`s and you're in trouble. `id`s are a bad idea. This is widely known.

Comment: Verbose won't throw.

Comment: I don't think you understand. No one is talking about linters. The use of `id`s is not recommended because they create Global properties and require code to be brittle which impedes it's ability to scale. This is widely known and understood. Using less specific ways to identify elements provides much more flexibility. `id`s should be avoided when possible (which is most of the time).

Comment: "require code to be brittle which impedes it's ability to scale"; This right here is so wrong on so many levels, I need to step away from this now. Glad I could help author with their request and avoiding inline policy blocks.